# Fetching data from a nested api in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to fetch the data ('userId','applicationId', 'application', 'role') in **userApplications** array. The dat from within from  within **userApplications** array doesn't fetch. This is the data:

```
     {
"userId": "7b46-c0015560fg8d4",
"username": "BA",
"firstName": "EMMANUEL",
"lastName": "JAMES",
"userApplications": [
  {
    "userId": "22b46-d00144nfd-hgf4",
    "applicationId": "8888-f66176cd5344",
    "application": "ReactShop",
    "role": "Programmer",
  }
]},
```

I would like to fetch the data ('userId','applicationId', 'application', 'role') in **userApplications** array. This is part of  my code:

```
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const[applicationId, setapplicationId]=useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
          console.log(result);
          setapplicationId(result.userApplications)
          console.log(result.userApplications)
        },

        error => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  
  function search(items) {
    return items.filter(item => {
      return searchParam.some(newItem => {
        return (
          item[newItem].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1
        );
      });
    });
  }

  if (error) {
    return <>{error.message}</>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <>loading...</>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="search-wrapper">
          <label htmlFor="search-form">
            <input
              type="search"
              name="search-form"
              id="search-form"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Search for..."
              value={q}
            
              onChange={e => setQ(e.target.value)}
            />
            <span className="sr-only">Search Users here</span>
          </label>
        </div>


        <div className="card-grid" className='font-poppins'>
          {search(items).map(item => (
            <div>
          
                <div className="card-content">
                
                  <div className="card-list card-body" >
                  <h5 class="card-title">{item.firstName}</h5>
               
                <p class="card-text">{item.username}</p>
                    <li>
                      First Name: <span>{item.firstName}</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      Last Name: <span>{item.lastName}</span>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                      User ID: <span>{item.userId}</span>
                    </li>
                    
                  
                    <li>
                      Application ID: <span>{item.userApplications.applicationId}</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      Application Name: <span>{item.userApplications.applicationId}</span>
                    </li>
                  </div>
                </div>
           
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
```

It doesn't fetch Application ID and Application Name

Comment: @Mwt_0239 I don't get an error but the data within the 'userApplications' like 'role', 'application', 'applicationId' doesn't fetch any result from the api

Comment: Can you show the console.log(res) & console.log(result) output for res & result (in your statement .then(res => res.json()).then(result)). What is exactly the output inside res & result ?